# Can I define a generic typescript Interface for the methods of a Class?

Tags: typescript

I'm cleaning up the types of my Angular 4 Application and I would like to define an interface to the `Database` classes in charge of the API calls.

Those classes will have methods receiving `Criteria` objects, and returning Observables of `ResultItems[]` that are widely different. So I've tried to define this Interface:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Database<C> {
  [methodName: string]: (args: C) => Observable<any>;
}
```

to cover the methods receiving a `Criteria` and returning `any`thing.

Then I try to have this kind of implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsDatabase<ItemsCriteria> implements Database<ItemsCriteria> {
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  fetch(args: ItemsCriteria): Observable<APIResponse[]> {
    return this.api.fetchItems(args);
  }

  summary(args: ItemsCriteria): Observable<SummaryResponse[]> {
    return this.api.itemsSummary(args);
  }
}
```

but Typescript denies it throwing:

```
Class 'ItemsDatabase<ItemsCriteria>' incorrectly implements interface 'Database<ItemsCriteria>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'ItemsDatabase<ItemsCriteria>'
```

Any advice? or this is just not possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the index signature to the class

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsDatabase<ItemsCriteria> implements Database<ItemsCriteria> {
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}
  [methodName: string]: (args: ItemsCriteria) => Observable<any>;
  fetch(args: ItemsCriteria): Observable<APIResponse[]> {
    return this.api.fetchItems(args);
  }

  summary(args: ItemsCriteria): Observable<SummaryResponse[]> {
    return this.api.itemsSummary(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, I hadn't seen something like that before, but now the constructor doesn't fit the Signature :( `Property 'api' of type 'ApiService' is not assignable to string index type '(args: ItemsCriteria) => Observable<any>'.` it seems that I should stick to a convention without type constraints.